# I have a SQL table which is like tree structure, I want to group it & count for depth 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have managed to group child group, now in that same, I want to some header count based on all child in that table

```
Head    child assigned total
In      In1     3       5
In      In2     2       3
In      In3     2       3
In      In4     1       3
In      In5     0       4
In      In6     4       4
In      In7     3       7
In      In8     2       3
Ma      Ma1     2       5
Ma      Ma2     0       5
Usr     us1     4       4
Usr     us2     1       3
```

So, I copied child's assigned, total column.

```
Head    assigned total  child assigned total
In          3       5   In1     3       5
In          2       3   In2     2       3
In          2       3   In3     2       3
In          1       3   In4     1       3
In          0       4   In5     0       4
In          4       4   In6     4       4
In          3       7   In7     3       7
In          2       3   In8     2       3
Ma          2       5   Ma1     2       5
Ma          0       5   Ma2     0       5
Us          4       4   us1     4       4
Us          1       3   us2     1       3
```

Now I want to group parent 1, So, all count of In (In1 - In8) should be sum and  be in header assignedHead, totalHead

```
Head    assigned total  child assigned total
In          17      32  In1     3       5
In          17      32  In2     2       3
In          17      32  In3     2       3
In          17      32  In4     1       3
In          17      32  In5     0       4
In          17      32  In6     4       4
In          17      32  In      3       7
In          17      32  In8     2       3
Ma          2       10  Ma1     2       5
Ma          2       10  Ma2     0       5
Us          5       7   us1     4       4
Us          5       7   us2     1       3
```

Or something like this which is efficient.

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different products with different implementations of sql. Therefore I temoved the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a window sum (if your RDBMS supports window functions):

```
select 
    head,
    assigned,
    total,
    sum(assigned) over(partition by head) sum_assigned,
    sum(total) over(partition by head) sum_total
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08a711f7221834a8f52ff282ee7bf4a5)**:

```
head | assigned | total | sum_assigned | sum_total
:--- | -------: | ----: | -----------: | --------:
In   |        3 |     5 |           17 |        32
In   |        2 |     3 |           17 |        32
In   |        2 |     3 |           17 |        32
In   |        1 |     3 |           17 |        32
In   |        0 |     4 |           17 |        32
In   |        4 |     4 |           17 |        32
In   |        3 |     7 |           17 |        32
In   |        2 |     3 |           17 |        32
Ma   |        2 |     5 |            2 |        10
Ma   |        0 |     5 |            2 |        10
Usr  |        4 |     4 |            5 |         7
Usr  |        1 |     3 |            5 |         7
```